# unable to remove patch from composer.json

Tags: magento2, patches, composer, remove

I have to update extension https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZ25K.png but it has an error, Can I remove it manually? I think it cant be good practice. how can I safe remove it? dockergento composer remove iwd/ordermanager didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the patch (deleting it manually) from your `composer.json` file , delete the patch file under `patches/composer/PatchName` and then run `composer install` .

Comment: yeah I did the same, I think that's it.